# Overriding where conditions in Laravel Query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am working on E-Commerce application, in which I am fetching the product which has the status 1. 
But there are situations where I need to fetch the product which has status 2 or 3.

I have overridden the `newQuery` method and added a condition for `status 1` in that method. Now I want to add another condition for `status 2`, but when I add this condition, the where clause will be duplicated in SQL query for that column(the default behavior of query builder).

Below is my code,

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true) {
    return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted)
     ->where('status', 1);                
}
```

When I need to fetch the product with status 2 as below

```
return $query->where('status', 2);
```

then the query formed will be as below

```
select * from `products` where `status` = 1 and `status` = 2
```

But I need an output like below query

```
select * from `products` where `status` = 2
```

Please suggest the way of doing it.

Comment: You shouldn't override `newQuery()` like this. Take a look at [global scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#global-scopes).

Answer (score 2):

Add a parameter to the newQuery function and pass in the status. When calling the newQuery function the default status would be 1, but if you supply an argument it will be whatever you pass to it.

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true, $status = 1) {
    return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted)
        ->where('status', $status);                
}
```

**EDIT**

This may be possible using [Dynamic Local Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes):

```
//Model

public function scopeStatus($query, $status = 1)
{
    return $query->where('status', $status);
}
```

and call like:

```
$result = App\MyModel::status(2)->get();
//OR To get with default "status"
$result = App\MyModel::status()->get();
```

Comment: Tried, but the query is same. The status will always be 1, as the newQuery() will be called without passing the second parameter. How can I pass the second parameter, when I will add a condition for status 2.

Comment: Where do you call `newQuery()`?

Comment: I defined it in a Product model.

Comment: If your desired result is to specify which status you want when you call the query you should craft your function in the model to accept an additional argument, this argument can be passed from the user in the view->controller->model through GET or POST request

Comment: @Nagesh This answer does work, you just need to add the param on the other side of your code. As the above answer shows, status will always be 1 by default unless defined otherwise.

Comment: @LegenJerry The newQuery method is called by Query builder initially whenever I call any model, so I cannot pass any extra parameter to that function, because I am not actually calling that function, Query builder is calling that function.

Comment: Sorry, I think what you want is query scope https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes . I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way of avoiding a blank call to status() (for default). So the status(2) will be for the where condition for 2, and if status(2) does not have any call, the status 1 will be considered. It will be like an API, so my users need not have to call a blank status(). Thanks.

Comment: Not that I know of. You could make it mandatory to supply an argument to `scopeStatus()`. Like `App\MyModel::status(1)->get();` and change your function signature to have `$status` be required and not optional. Other than that you could check out global scopes, maybe you can use that in addition to a local scope. However I don't have an instance of Laravel to try this out with. If this is an acceptable answer, can you please mark my answer as accepted?